# Codeigniter ajax form validation for radio button not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

i was trying to do a simple form validation using ajax in Codeigniter which has a text field and 3 radio buttons... The form error for textfield is showing the error but the error for radio button not showing...

Please Help...

### HTML Page

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('register') ?>" method="POST" id="regID">
        <div class="form-field">
            <input type="radio" name="cars" value="BMW">BMW
            <input type="radio" name="cars" value="Ferrari">Ferrari
            <input type="radio" name="cars" value="Audi">Audi
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="submitter">
    </form>
```

### Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#regID").submit(function(){
        var form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url  : form.attr('action'),
            type : form.attr('method'),
            data : form.serialize(),
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(response){
                if(response.success == true)
                {               
                    alert('DONE');              
                }
                else
                {
                    $.each(response.messages, function(index, value){
                        var element = $('#'+index);                     

                        $(element)  
                        .closest('.form-field')                     
                        .find('.text-danger').remove();                     

                        $(element).after(value);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

</script>
```

### Controller

```
public function register() 
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required',
            array(
                'required' => 'Name Required',
                )
            );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cars', 'Cars', 'required',
            array(
                'required' => 'Cars Required',
                )
            );

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">* ', '</p>');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
            $validator['success'] = true;                   
        }
        else
        {           
            $validator['success'] = false;
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
            {
                $validator['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($validator);
    }
```

When i did this, i could display error only for text field, not for radio button.. If all the radio buttons left unchecked, i want to run the validation error....

How can i do this... Please Help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed your code at my end. The only issue I found is I am not getting **cars** key in $_POST array. If we are not getting this key in array then how does the error validation of this part work:

```
else
    {           
        $validator['success'] = false;
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
        {
            $validator['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
        }
    }
```

You are using $_POST array and it does not have **cars** key init

**Solution:** Make any one radio input selected by default. Such as:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('register') ?>" method="POST" id="regID">
    <div class="form-field">
        <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="cars" value="BMW">BMW
        <input type="radio" name="cars" value="Ferrari">Ferrari
        <input type="radio" name="cars" value="Audi">Audi
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="submitter">
</form>
```

Once you set any option as default then you don't need to check required validation. Otherwise, yo can use other validation rules.

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Thanks @RobertWillis